# Change buttons text in container view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple container view with button inside of this container view

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

The `class` of container view in intarface builder is the initial `"View Controller"`, but if i want to change text

```
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButton.setTitle("aaa", for: .normal)
}
```

I have an error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
>   How correctly use elements from container view?

Comment: please make sure outlet is connected properly

Comment: Show proper code, how you implement container view.

Comment: it's definitely problem with "myButton" outlet connection.